# numpy, do multiple operations cause intermediate arrays to be created?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm wondering if these two are equivalent:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(100000) + 1

# 1
b = 10 * np.log10(a)

# 2
c = np.empty_like(a)
c = np.multiply(10, np.log10(a, out=c), out=c)
```

More precisely, I wonder if numpy found some way to create array `b` without having an intermediate array that needs to be allocated and thrown away later for the result of the log operation. Of course, this only matters for very big arrays.

Comment: Yes, yes they do. if you are looking for an alternative when working at the limits of memory, consider using [numexpr](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html) to avoid the intermediate arrays

Comment: Just to clarify: by "yes they do" you mean they do create intermediate arrays in case #1 right? in case #2 not, but it's a bit more ugly, i suppose.

Comment: yes in case 1, no in case 2.

Comment: Note that `np.log10(a, out=c); np.multiply(10, c, out=c)` would be cleaner and less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of computing time, they seem to be roughly similar, although the first version is a bit better:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(100_000, dtype=float) + 1

In [3]: def f(a):
   ...:     b = 10 * np.log10(a)
   ...:

In [4]: def g(a):
   ...:     c = np.empty_like(a)
   ...:     c = np.multiply(10, np.log10(a, out=c), out=c)
   ...:

In [5]: %timeit f(a)
759 µs ± 52.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit g(a)
877 µs ± 39.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Interesting result. Would be worthwhile understanding why the first performs better.

Comment: Definitely. I have no idea though. Honestly, the result of `%timeit` does vary between runs, sometimes `g` does better than `f`. I'd say that generally speaking they're kind of the same.